# How to sum rows in a tsv file using awk?

Tags: bash, awk

My input:

```
Position   A   B   C   D   No
1   0   0   0   0   0
2   1   0   1   0   0
3   0   6   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0
5   0   5   0   0   0
```

I have a TSV file, like the above, where I wish to sum the rows of numbers in the ABCD columns only, not the Position column. 
Desired output would have a TSV, two columns with Position and Sum in the first row,

```
Position   Sum
1    0
2    2
3    6
4    0
5    5
```

So far I have:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print"Position\tSum"}{if(NR==1)next; sum=$2+$3+$4+$5 printf"%d\t%d\n",$sum}' infile.tsv > outfile.tsv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close, try this:

```
 awk 'BEGIN{print"Position\tSum"}{if(NR==1)next; sum=$2+$3+$4+$5; printf "%d\t%d\n",$1,sum; }' infile.tsv > outfile.tsv
```

But I say it's way cleaner with newlines and spaces:

```
awk '
BEGIN { 
    print"Position\tSum";
}
{  
    if (NR==1) {
        next; 
    }
    sum = $2 + $3 + $4 + $5 + $6; 
    printf "%d\t%d\n", $1, sum;
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hard coding field numbers, which will not work in many cases, I have a loop approach. We skip the first field and take the sum of all remaining fields.

```
awk 'FNR==1{print $1,"sum";next} {for(i=2;i<NF;i++){sum+=$i};print $1,sum;sum=""}' Input_file
```

Change `awk` to `awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}` (the rest of the code stays the same) if you need output in TAB form.

Comment: @SaltedPork, glad that it helpded you, give it sometime and you could select any of the answer as a correct answer too, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

a minimalist script can be

```
$ awk '{print $1 "\t" (NR==1?"Sum":$2+$3+$4+$5)}' file
```